# Same Comment box in wordpress across multiple pages

Tags: wordpress, comments

quick question:

is it possible to have the SAME comment box across multiple pages in Wordpress?

I wanted to show the exact same comments on 4-5 different pages.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've added the code below (it's in Portuguese) that I've tried inserting on a post per post basis, but I believe I'm screwing up on setting the right post-id for both to which post the comment should be related to and then parsing it on other pages

```
<?php
// Do not delete these lines
    if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
        die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

    if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
        <p class="nocomments">Este artigo está protegido por password. Insira-a para ver os comentários.</p>
    <?php
        return;
    }
?>

<div id="comments">
    <h3><?php comments_number('0 Comentários', '1 Comentário', '% Comentários' );?></h3>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
                //Gather comments for a specific page/post 
                $comments = get_comments(array(
                    'post_id' => 156,
                    'status' => 'approve' //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
                ));

                //Display the list of comments
                wp_list_comments(array(
                    'per_page' => 10, //Allow comment pagination
                    'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
                ), $comments);
            ?>
        </ol>

    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>

    <div id="respond">
            <h3>Deixe o seu comentário!</h3>

            <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
            <fieldset>
                <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

                <p>Autentificado como <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Sair desta conta">Sair desta conta &raquo;</a></p>

                <?php else : ?>

                <label for="author">Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" />

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" />

                <label for="url">Website:</label>
                <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" />

                <?php endif; ?>

                <label for="comment">Mensagem:</label>
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="" cols=""></textarea>

                <input type="submit" class="commentsubmit" value="Enviar Comentário" />

                <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
                <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <p class="cancel"><?php cancel_comment_reply_link('Cancelar Resposta'); ?></p>
        </div>
     <?php else : ?>
        <h3>Os comentários estão fechados.</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you even searched Google?! A simple 'Wordpress show comments' search lists [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) as the first result, and that page tells you exactly how to do it.

Comment: I have ... but due to my limited knowledge I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. I should have been more specific on my question and for that I apologize.

I'll explain further below. Thanks for your answer mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. See the Codex for [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) -

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php
        //Gather comments for a specific page/post 
        $comments = get_comments(array(
            'post_id' => XXX,
            'status' => 'approve' //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
        ));

        //Display the list of comments
        wp_list_comments(array(
            'per_page' => 10, //Allow comment pagination
            'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
        ), $comments);
    ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hey mate thanks for that

Only problem I wasn't that clear on my question as I said above.

What I really wanted was to show both comments AND the comment box with name, email, website and place for answer across all pages

But I can't get it to work. I've tried the code from [this page](http://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-template-wordpress-comments/) in addition to what you've posted above.

Problem is I can't get it to show the comments and the comment box across all pages the right way. Probably is stg with the post_id thing, but I don't really know how to code it right =/